# Mismatched input '...' Expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script

I get the error message on line 15:  "Mismatched input 'strategy.entry' Expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.

Code:

```
//@version=5

fastL=12
slowL=26
macdL=9

MACD=ta.ema(close,fastL)-ta.ema(close,slowL)
signal=ta.ema(MACD,macdL)

plot(MACD, title="MACD_line",color=color.blue)
plot(signal,title="signal_line",color=color.orange)

If (MACD[1]<0 and MACD>MACD[1])
    strategy.entry("strategy.Long",strategy.long)
If (MACD[1]>0 and MACD<MACD[1])
    strategy.entry("strategy.Short",strategy.Short)
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: check your indentation

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to use if instead of If
2. You have to use strategy.long/strategy.short instead of strategy.Long/strategy.Short

Code

```
//@version=5
strategy("Test")
fastL=12
slowL=26
macdL=9
MACD=ta.ema(close,fastL)-ta.ema(close,slowL)
signal=ta.ema(MACD,macdL)
plot(MACD, title="MACD_line",color=color.blue) 
plot(signal,title="signal_line",color=color.orange)
if (MACD[1]<0 and MACD>MACD[1]) 
    strategy.entry("strategy.long",strategy.long)
if (MACD[1]>0 and MACD<MACD[1]) 
    strategy.entry("strategy.short",strategy.short)
```